# Eclipse EGit Committing fails - Caused by: java.io.EOFException

Tags: eclipse, exception, commit, egit

Details of the error are below.  I have just installed on a new Windows 7 machine and am getting this error on any commit done in EGit.  I can successfully commit using the Git Bash shell.  I checked for updates to EGit, but none were found.  Other EGit functions like pull and push do work, but I have to do the commit in the Git shell.

An internal error occurred
Exception caught during execution of commit command

**Stack trace**:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of commit command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.call(CommitCommand.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CommitOperation.commit(CommitOperation.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CommitOperation.access$7(CommitOperation.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CommitOperation$1.run(CommitOperation.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2326)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CommitOperation.execute(CommitOperation.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.commit.CommitUI$2.run(CommitUI.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Input did not match supplied length. 239 bytes are missing.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryInserter.shortInput(ObjectDirectoryInserter.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryInserter.toTemp(ObjectDirectoryInserter.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryInserter.insert(ObjectDirectoryInserter.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.createTemporaryIndex(CommitCommand.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.call(CommitCommand.java:195)
    ... 8 more
```

**Session Data:**

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.6.0_32
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
```

Aha, found this on the Eclipse Egit Community forum describing a nearly idenditcal problem: [http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/820938/?srch=eofexception#msg_820938](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/820938/?srch=eofexception#msg_820938)

The solution was to install the latest nightly build for both EGit and JGit from here:  [http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly/](https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly/)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my case removing index.lock file from the .git folder of the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my ubuntu 14.04, I installed jgit [ sudo apt-get install jgit-cli
] and the problem is solved. After the installation I restarted netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Yes by removing index.lock file from the .git folder of the project it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by changing the user group to the current user on Ubuntu 16.04. Hope that helps.

cd project_directory
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 .

Answer (score -1):

I commited one file at the time until I found the "damaged" file.
In my case it was a word file.  I didn't commmit it